# How To Prevent Checked-Out Documents When Adding Document Cancelled

Tags: document-library, check-out

In my document library, "require documents to be checked out before they can be edited" set to NO. When the user uploads the document and the metadata form appears, if the user cancels or closes the window, the document is added and checked-out. I want no checked-out items in library. How can i prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. If mandatory metadata is not filled in, the document will not be visible to anyone else but the author. Either don't make the metadata fields required or educate the users in the proper procedure to supply required metadata.